# Rails Webrick: Configure what directories are watched for changes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, webrick

At the moment I'm having to restart the server if I change files in the lib/ and app/helpers/ directories. Is there a way to configure either Rails or Webrick such that it hotswaps the files in those directories as well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `config/application.rb`:

```
config.autoload_paths += %W(#{config.root}/lib #{config.root}/app/helpers)
```

There should be a commented line which explains what `autoload_paths` is for.